# ERROR: ValidationError: CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

**SITUATION:**

It seems I must have made a mistake in my Mongoose Model or in one of the parameters that are passed to the route.

I am fairly new to the angular2 architecture, so the mistake might be quite obvious.

**ERROR:**

```
  ERROR: ValidationError: CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{ title: 'das',
      username: 'John',
      choice1: 'FSDAFASDF',
      choice2: 'FDSAFD',
      counter1: 11,
      counter2: 0,
      pollId: '5920598ade7567001170c810',
      userId: '591c15b3ebbd170aa07cd476' }" at path "poll"
```

---

**CODE:**

**route**

```
router.patch('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
      user.votes = req.body.votes;
      user.save(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR: "+err);
              return res.status(500).json({
                  title: 'An error occurred',
                  error: err
              });
          }
          res.status(201).json({
              poll: 'Vote Saved',
              obj: result
          });
      });
   });
});
```

**models/user:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    polls: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'}],
    votes: [{
      poll: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'},
      choice: {type: Number},
    }],
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**models/poll**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = require('./user');

var schema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    choice1: {type: String, required: true},
    choice2: {type: String, required: true},
    counter1: {type: Number, required: true},
    counter2: {type: Number, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

schema.post('remove', function (poll) {
    User.findById(poll.user, function (err, user) {
        user.polls.pull(poll);
        user.save();
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', schema);
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
router.patch('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    console.log("VALID ID ? :"+mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(decoded.user._id));
    console.log("DECODED USER ID:"+ decoded.user._id);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(decoded.user._id, {votes: req.body.votes}, function (err, user) {
      user.save(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR: "+err);
              return res.status(500).json({
                  title: 'An error occurred',
                  error: err
              });
          }
          res.status(201).json({
              poll: 'Vote Saved',
              obj: result
          });
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: `Cast to ObjectId` errors usually means that mongoose failed to find a document by it's ID either because the ID is deformed (like 'undefined` or not really an instance of Mongo ObjectID). Can you check that `decoded.user._id` in `router` and `poll.user` in models/poll really are valid IDs?

Comment: @borislemke the decoded id looks fine :D

Comment: could you kindly check whether `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(decoded.user._id)` returns `true`? Or did you check with database that that `_id` really exists?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I found the issue

Comment: @borislemke `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(decoded.user._id)` returns `true`.

Comment: @borislemke Oh great :D

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're trying to save an entire poll object to `votes.poll`, but it should be the id of the poll instead

Comment: @Creynders Thanks, that got me to find the solution.

Comment: @Creynders Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: From your "EDIT" code block, you use `user.save` after using `findByIdAndUpdate`, `user.save` is not necessary as mongoose already updates and saves your new user model. This will cause the same error of mongoose not being able to cast the `ObjectId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thoughtfully guessing that this particular piece of code is what causes the issue:

```
    ...
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
      user.votes = req.body.votes;
      user.save(function(err, result) {
    ...
```

mongoose is trying to resave the model and overwrite it's `_id` property with a plain string, whereas it should be an instance of the `ObjectId`.

Instead of using save to update your model, please try to use `findByIdAndUpdate` instead. If this is working, than my guess would be correct.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(decode.user._id, {votes: req.body.votes}, function (err, user) {
```

Or, cast the string `_id` into an `ObjectId` manually

```
    ...
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
      user.votes = req.body.votes;
      user._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id);
      user.save(function(err, result) {
    ...
```

The first is preferred.

Comment: Neither work :D but I think you have the right intuition. The error for the first one is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Comment: @Coder1000 did you find a solution to your problem? What was the solution?

Comment: Creynders pointed me in the right direction: "Somewhere in your code you're trying to save an entire poll object to votes.poll, but it should be the id of the poll instead" That was it.

Comment: Since you helped me and creynders is not answering, I am giving you an upvote and accepting your answer :D Because you helped me.